# Using enotez for getting endnotes at the end AND footnotes on each page (like we used to get from the endnotes package)

Tags: footnotes, endnotes, enotez

I wish to reproduce the following using the enotez package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}

My text\footnote{my footnote}

\newpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

The above gives me footnotes ***and*** endnotes.

My attempt :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}

\begin{document}

My text\footnote{my footnote}

\newpage

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

This is giving my ***only*** footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

My text\footnote{my footnote}

\newpage

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

This is giving my ***only*** endnotes.

How do I get ***both footnotes and endnotes*** from enotez package ?

Comment: The first example prints just a footnote and no endnotes.

Comment: I was reading this : https://web.archive.org/web/20120516064001/http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-footnotes.shtml#endnotes The \listofendnotes should replace \theendnotes I think you are right, I am a little confused now.

Comment: I wish to get footnotes ***and*** endnotes from each \footnote incantation in the text using enotez package. Can someone show me how to do that?

Comment: So you want that `\footnote` both does `\footnote` and `\endnote` with the same text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `\footnote` to issue both `\footnote` and `\endnote`; this of course requires to use an alias of the original `\footnote` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={52mm,74mm}]{geometry} % just to make a smaller picture

\usepackage{enotez}

\NewCommandCopy{\enotezfootnote}{\footnote}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\footnote}{om}{%
 \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\enotezfootnote{#2}\endnote{#2}}
   {\enotezfootnote[#1]{#2}\endnote[#1]{#2}}%
}
\makeatletter
\setenotez{mark-cs=\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

My text\footnote{my footnote}

My text\footnote{my second footnote}

\clearpage
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we can do this in Latex-2. The \footnote takes ***two*** arguments. I have used only the mandatory argument in redefining it. Can you please show me how I would check for the optional first argument like you do in your answer @egreg in this case ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enotez}

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{
  \oldfootnote{#1}\endnote{#1}
}

% Without this we get ***two*** marks, one from the footnote
% and one from the endnote. This disables the endnote mark.

\makeatletter
\setenotez{mark-cs=\@gobble}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

My text\footnote{my footnote}
My text\footnote{my second footnote}

\clearpage
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```